# Owned Entity Collections usage

Tags: ef-core-2.2

When I run the following code I get an exception saying that "The entity type 'ElementWeight' requires a primary key to be defined".  Why do I need a key if I want to treat ElementWeight as a value-type?

```
var context = new DataContext(options);

context.Weightings.Add(new ImportWeighting { Name="temp", Weights = new List<ElementWeight>
    { new ElementWeight { Mag_dB = 1.0, Phase_deg = 10.0 },
        new ElementWeight { Mag_dB = 2.0, Phase_deg = 20.0 }
    } });
```

In the OnModelCreating I do the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImportWeighting>().OwnsMany(c => c.Weights);
}
```

And here are the classes

```
public class ImportWeighting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ElementWeight> Weights { get; set; }
}

public class ElementWeight
{
    public double Mag_dB { get; set; }
    public double Phase_deg { get; set; }
}
```

If I add a key as the documentations shows then I get an error that the items already exists

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Distributor>().OwnsMany(p => p.ShippingCenters, a =>
{
    a.HasForeignKey("DistributorId");
    a.Property<int>("Id");
    a.HasKey("DistributorId", "Id");
});
```

Comment: *"Why do I need a key if I want it treated ElementWeight as a value-type?"* I would also like to know the answer. Unfortunately the only one who can answer that question is some EF Core team member.